# DataSource valid connection but getURL returns null?

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, datasource, informix

I had this situation reported to me with Informix over Payara (Glassfish).

Is there any cases where we could get a valid connection but DatabaseMetaData getURL could return null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create an Informix JDBC connection from a DataSource, then from the driver's perspective there is no URL, and `DatabaseMetaData.getURL()` will return null.

If you make a connection using `DriverManager` and pass in a URL, then you should get that URL back from the metadata.

One could argue that the connection could 'build' a URL from the `DataSource` to give back to you, but the Informix JDBC driver today does not do that.

Answer (score 2):

Returning `null` from [`DatabaseMetaData.getURL()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getURL()) is allowed, as stated in the Javadoc:

> **Returns:**
> the URL for this DBMS or `null` if it cannot be generated

The `DatabaseMetaData.getURL()` method is primarily intended for informational purposes, so you shouldn't rely on its result in any way.

Probably the Informix driver has no way to obtain the original URL used for the connection and simply returns `null` in its implementation of `DatabaseMetaData.getURL()`.

Comment: Yeah but I'm trying to figure out WHY would this happen.

Comment: @sproketboy Have you checked the `DatabaseMetaData` implementation of Informix? Maybe it always returns `null`, some drivers simply don't bother to implement those types of database metadata methods, and even if they bother it might not be the exact same URL as was used to connect.